# The space is complete iff the subspace and the quotient space is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F$ be a closed subspace of a normed space. How to prove that $E$ is complete iff $F$ and $E/F$ are both complete ?

Comment: Use the fact that a space is complete iff absolutely convergent series also converge. Then show that $E/F$ is Banach. Since $F$ is closed, and $E$ complete, a cauchy sequence in $F$ converges to some $x$, but since $F$ is closed, it converges in $F$.

Comment: Regarding the second comment, see the more general statement: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240640/a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-is-a-banach-space

Comment: It is not duplicate. The question which you gave the link to proves one side of the claim ($X$ complete and $Y$ closed $\Rightarrow$ $X/Y$ complete). The question here asks to prove the reverse implication also( which is not there in the given link).

Answer (score 7):

Let $\pi: E \to E/F$ be the quotient map.  Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $E$.  Then $\pi(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $E/F$, so has a limit which is $\pi(z)$ for some $z \in E$.  Since $\|\pi(x_n - z)\| = \inf \{\|x_n - z - y\|: y \in F\}$, there is $y_n \in F$ with $\|x_n - z - y_n\| < \|\pi(x_n - z) \| + 1/n$, and thus
$\|x_n - z - y_n\| \to 0$.  Show that $y_n$ is Cauchy, and then that $x_n$ converges to $z + \lim_n y_n$.

Comment: what is $\pi_n$ ?

Comment: how to show that $y_n$ is cauchy ?

Comment: Sorry, $\pi_n$ was a typo (fixed).  $y_n$ is Cauchy because $\|y_n - y_m\|  \le \|x_n - z - y_n\| +\|x_m - x_n\| +  \|x_m - z - y_m\| $.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What if we take $E=F$ and $E$ not complete? where this proof use the fact that $F$ is proper subspace.

Comment: @MeetPatel If $E = F$, $E/E = \{(0)\}$ is complete, so the statement just says $E$ is complete iff $E$ is complete.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes I missed that $F$ also has to be complete.